# Asp.net Email receive problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I'm using `MailMessage` class and then sent mail to many recipients. My code is here.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mysite.com");
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@mysite.com", "mypassword");
forea(User u in users)
{
  msg.To.Add(u.Email);
}

client.Send(msg);
```

This work successfully.

But problem is **all email shown** on the recipient computer. `TO: user1.fds.com;email2.fdsa.com;email3.fdsa.com;...` etc.

I need to show only current user email. How to do it?

Maybe i will do it like this

```
forea(User u in users)
{
  msg.To.Clear();
  msg.To.Add(u.Email);
  client.Send(msg);
}
```

But it is too slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [`MailMessage.Bcc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx) instead of `To`. That won't show the recipient in the "To" line of course, but usually that's not a problem.

I do hope the "many recipients" genuinely want this mail...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you iterate over the list of recipients and send the emails one at a time.

Using BCC may cause the mail to be classed as spam.

Comment: +1 and would be fine: 
users.ConvertAll(u => new MailMessage(u.Email)).ForEach(client.Send)