# Send many mail problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I'm creating newsletter in asp.net. I'm sending to 2000 email recipients. This operation iterate every mail and send using SMTP mail. [Please see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369251/asp-net-email-receive-problem) .My server use hmailserver.

My problem is

Sometimes this error shown:  Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.1.1  Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table

or

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unknown user Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unknown user

Comment: What is your question?  That behaviour looks like what I'd expect in a mailing list of 2000 addresses; some of them will no longer be (if ever they were) valid.

Comment: I think his issue is, when one of the receipt is failed, the mail is not going to other's because exception thrown and whole process is not completed.

Comment: You'll need to do every send inside a try-catch block, log any exceptions that occur, carry on with the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should send mail to each recipient separately. But instead of using [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) method use [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) method. You can hook [SendCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted.aspx) so you know which recepient passed a which failed.